# jquery get input value changed from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, onchange, elfinder

I'm working with elFinder on standalone popup. When I choose an image from elFinder it inserts the path of the image into the parent window input. The file comes from elFinder iframe. Now I want to trigger an event in the parent window when the input changes, grab that value and add it to image source.

```
<input name="media" type="hidden" value="" id="media" />
<img src="" id="show_media" style="display: none" />
<script>
  $('#media').on('change', function() {
     $('#show_media').attr('src', $(this).val()).show();
  })
</script>
```

but it's not working, the image source it's not updating, but the input receives the file path from elFinder

Comment: A little question: is the callback function called or not ?

Comment: no, is not changing anything

Comment: What I am not understanding is this: if the callback function is called but not doing anything or it is not called at all. This info is needed to understanding where the problem is.

Comment: the callback function is called, but it's not doing anything, I tried to do a simple console.log() and still no results, I also call the function on document.ready() so if the page reloads the image is still in place and it works fine, but only onchange doesn't work, it feels like it's not triggering the `onchange`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$('#media').on('change', function() {
     $('#show_media').attr('src', $(this).val()).show();
}).triggerHandler('change');
```